# Searching for 2 word key in dictionary

Tags: python

im new in python and world of programming. get to the point. when i run this code and put input let say chicken, it will reply as two leg animal. but i cant get reply for two words things that has space in between like space monkey(althought it appear in my dictionary) so how do i solve it???

my dictionary: example.py

```
dictionary2 = {
    "chicken":"chicken two leg animal",
    "fish":"fish is animal that live under water",
    "cow":"cow is big vegetarian animal",
    "space monkey":"monkey live in space",
```

my code: test.py

```
from example import *

print "how can i help you?"
print

user_input = raw_input()

print
print "You asked: " + user_input + "."
response = "I will get back to you. "

input_ls = user_input.split(" ")
processor = {
    "dictionary2":False,
    "dictionary_lookup":[]
}
for w in input_ls:

    if w in dictionary2:
        processor["dictionary2"] = True
        processor["dictionary_lookup"].append(w)

if processor["dictionary2"] is True:
    dictionary_lookup = processor["dictionary_lookup"][0]
    translation = dictionary2[dictionary_lookup]
    response = "what you were looking for is: " + translation

print
print "Response: " + response
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the user input? Just use the whole input as the key in the dictionary.

Comment: usually, the user input will be like "what is chicken", so my code detect chicken in dictionary and give answer based on that

Comment: You need to design a parser that knows how to get rid of noise words like "what is".

Comment: Or instead of splitting the input, loop through the dictionary, testing if any of the keys can be found in the input.

Comment: AI is tough. Why are you trying to do this as a beginning programmer? You need to learn to walk before you can run.

Comment: Maybe something like `[dictionary2[i] for i in dictionary2.keys() if i in input_ls]` ?

Comment: the question could be in any form like, define the meaning of, give definition for. im sorry for asking this but i thought when i can get answer for 1 word, its not that dificult for more than 1 words

Comment: You have to study the comparison with type list, dictionary and string. In your case, I think you wants to compare the string in the dictionary key. So that you have to extract all the keys in the dictionary first by `dict.keys()` and than check the strings from the key_list one by one, you could use `enumerate(list())` or even a `for` loop, and to do some matching.

Comment: thank you @M.Leung i will look into what you just said. seems interesting.

Comment: @saitama, pls checkout my answer that provides solution by dynamic substitution using `re` that can handle any number of input words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explain your purpose to get better help.
In your case you seem to be only interested in looking up words and then this code should be sufficient. Notice the .format() syntax which cleans up your code drastically.

**updated code** : now a list is created with the combinations found in the input. This however might need modification to fit needs.

```
dictionary2 = {
"chicken":"chicken two leg animal",
"fish":"fish is animal that live under water",
"cow":"cow is big vegetarian animal",
"space monkey":"monkey live in space"}

print("how can i help you?")
user_input = raw_input()
print("You asked: {}.".format(user_input))

split = user_input.split(" ")
combos = [' '.join(split[x:y]) for x in range(len(split)) for y in range(len(split)+1) if ' '.join(split[x:y]) != ""]

# Create an empty dictionary to insert found item
response = {}

for item in combos:
    if dictionary2.get(item):
        response[item] = "what you were looking for is: {}.".format(dictionary2[item])

# If dictionary is empty do this
if not response:
    print("Response: I will get back to you!")

# If not, loop over keys(k) and values(v) and print them with an index(ind)
for ind, (k,v) in enumerate(response.iteritems()):
    print("Response {}: {} ({})".format(ind+1, v, k))
```

Comment: ty @Anton vBR. actually what i want is that you can put any kind of words. ex: what is fish. notice that by using your code, there will be no answer since the sentence is not in dictionary. my code on the other hand helps split the sentence and check every words that match in dictionary. the problem is i cant match string with 2 words. ex: space monkey. i cant call it cause it only detect 1 word. i truly appreciate your help

Comment: @saitama Perfect! Now you are explaining things more clearly. This is what we wanted from the start. However... there are still many questions: what about multiple inputs in the same row? or is it just the first one? Look at my updated code for an example. The key is the *combos** variable which creates a list of different combinations. Use print(combos) to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is when you use `for w in input_ls` and what you passed was "space monkey", it looks for space, then it looks for monkey. If you want the desired results with this specific script, it'd look like this

```
print "how can i help you?"
print

user_input = raw_input()

print
print "You asked: " + user_input + "."
response = "I will get back to you. "

input_ls = user_input
processor = {
    "dictionary2":False,
    "dictionary_lookup":[]
}

if input_ls in dictionary2:
    processor["dictionary2"] = True
    processor["dictionary_lookup"].append(input_ls)

if processor["dictionary2"] is True:
    dictionary_lookup = processor["dictionary_lookup"][0]
    translation = dictionary2[dictionary_lookup]
    response = "what you were looking for is: " + translation

print
print "Response: " + response
```

note I also changed `input_ls = user_input.split(" ")` to `input_ls = user_input` because that turns your string into an array of individual words, which wouldn't return what you're looking for if you're trying to look up specific phrases instead of individual words, and made this important change here

```
if input_ls in dictionary2:
    processor["dictionary2"] = True
    processor["dictionary_lookup"].append(input_ls)
```

--edit--

I had to clock out for work, but now that I'm home I can address this better. When trying to accomplish this goal using a dictionary, here's how I would've done it.

```
dictionary2 = {
    "red":"the color red",
    "blue":"fish is animal that live under water",
    "red and blue":"these colors make blue",
    "blue and yellow":"these colors make green"
}
user_input = raw_input('what would you like?\t')
user_input = user_input.split(' ')
print
for word in user_input:
    for key,val in dictionary2.iteritems():
        if word in key:
            print '%s: %s' % (key,val)
```

When trying to iterate through a dictionary, you need to use either:

dictionary2.iteritems() for both key and val

dictionary2.iterkeys() for your keys

dictionary2.itervalues() for your values

Comment: even then, I wouldn't say this is the best way to go about it, but it answers the question

Comment: thank you for your help @saniboy. its true what you code. but i want it to be more flexible, the user can type "what is space monkey" then the code detect 'space' and 'monkey', combine both, check in dict and give result. i know its really hard. my mistake. anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've redone my answer even though an answer is chosen as this was an interesting problem and I was close to a fair solution in given time.

This answers can take human like questions instead of just words.

Although, for true machine learning `nltk` is a better option. For start we can use something like below.

It used builtin library `difflib`  to match question against dictionary keys and decided which has higher probability.

> Warning: Exception handling is not implemented. It will just pick up max probable match.

We then use `re` to remove  words in key from answer and put everything back together. This provides a more natural answer than just displaying key values.

```
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similarity(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

dictionary2 = {
    "chicken":"chicken two leg animal",
    "fish":"fish is animal that live under water",
    "cow":"cow is big vegetarian animal",
    "space monkey":"monkey live in space",}

user_input = raw_input("User Question:")

#Check which key has greater probability match
similarity_list = []
for i in dictionary2.keys():
    similarity_list.append((i,similarity(user_input,i))) 

key_match = max(similarity_list, key=lambda x:x[1])

uin = ('|'.join(key_match[0].split()))
p = re.compile(r"\b(" + uin + ")\\W", re.I)
ans = p.sub('', dictionary2[key_match[0]])
print "answer: {} {}".format(key_match[0], ans)
```

**Result**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
User Question:what is a chicken?
answer: chicken two leg animal
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
User Question:Where does space monkey live?
answer: space monkey live in space
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
User Question:Where does fish live?
answer: fish is animal that live under water
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
User Question:what is a cow?
answer: cow is big vegetarian animal
>>>
```

Comment: thank you @Anil_M. i must say your answer is the most close to what i want. again, thank you :)

Comment: I hope u can select my answer then and any up vote  is appreciated as well